# Unexpected token illegal - Regex - MVC 3 JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to know why some times code is not in one line and what I have to do to fix it? (Problem with regex?) It is look like this:

```
**var PelnyOpisEdytuj = '@Model.PelnyOpis';**
```

Problem example:
[image]

Comment: Oh man, look at that var name... =)

Comment: @Andre Calil it`s not important :)

Comment: Not at all, it's just... funny =)

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with your code that generates JavaScript (so posting that code could be helpful). In general I don't think it is good idea to mix JavaScript into server side code (on of the reasons - it is unnecessarily painful to properly escape generated JavaScript code, especially if it includes multiple levels of string constructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution maybe is not perfect but work correct. I created div with argument and later I take data. There was problem with regex.

```
<div id="DivExample" style="display: none;">
@Html.Raw(@Model.ExampleText)
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //komenatatz zapytanie
    var DivExampleData= $('#DivExample').text();
</script>
```